# crontab python script error with dependencies

Tags: python, cron

I have an scheduled crontab to run every minute that calls a shell script that runs the python script. My problem is that I get an ModuleNotFoundError. I'm a newbie in terms of cronjobs and Linux

crontab

`* * * * * sh /home/pablo_racana/queries/test.sh >> out.txt 2>&1`

sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd "$(dirname "$0")";
CWD="$(pwd)"
echo $CWD
PYTHONPATH=/home/pablo_racana/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
HOME=/home/pablo_racana
python3 test_cron.py
```

python script

```py
import datetime
import sys
import pyodbc
import json
import struct
import adal
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
```

For each iteration I receive the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_cron.py", line 6, in <module>
    import adal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'adal'
```

I saw in a different answer that I needed to add the PYTHONPATH to where my package is installed, but in my case, I have packages instaled in different folders

```py
import pyodbc
print(pyodbc)
/home/pablo_racana/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

```py
import adal
print(adal)
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved.

I added the following script with the filepaths

```py
import sys
sys.path.append(r'/home/pablo_racana/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
sys.path.append(r'/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/')
```